# Problems Importing CSV File as a List into Python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I generated a list of urls into a Python list named `MasterList` using Beautiful Soup and I would like to save this list as a text or .csv file to then import into other Python scraping scripts as a list that I can iterate over and feed into Beautiful Soup.  I don't want to use pickle or import the functions that generate `MaterList` into my other script files because generating `MasterList` takes a very long time so I only want to generate it once and use it repeatedly. So I saved `MasterList` using the following

```
import csv

ListCsv=csv.writer(open("MasterList.csv","w"))
ListCsv.writerow(MasterList)
```

and the file shows up in my directory as a .csv file populated with the correct information. However, when I try running the code

```
test = csv.reader(open("MasterList.csv","r"))
test = list(test)
print(test)
```

I don't get any errors and the list `test` is empty. That is, the `print(test)` command displays `[]`. I've looked around many forums and tried different variations of importing the csv file to save as a list and nothing has worked. Depending on the syntax and method I use, I either get and empty list or `print(test)` displays `<_csv.reader object at 0x1014c78a0>`.

I should add that I am using Python Ver 2.7.3 on Mac OSX 10.7.5 and I have installed the latest version of the csv module. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `with` statement for  handling files, or explicitly close the file object.

Answer (score 1):

You should close the file object explicitly or better use a `with` statement for handling file as it'll automatically close the file for you, otherwise the data you actually wrote to the file might not be flushed to it yet.

**Demo:**

```
>>> f = open('abc.csv', 'w')
>>> writer = csv.writer(f)
>>> writer.writerow(range(10))
>>> list(csv.reader(open("abc.csv"))) #empty result, nothing flushed to file yet.
[]
>>> f.close()             #close the file object, now the data is flushed to file
>>> list(csv.reader(open("abc.csv")))
[['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']]
```

Better use the `with` statement:

```
with open('abc.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(range(10))
with open('abc.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print list(reader)
```

Comment: Great thanks! Two follow up questions: How do I save `list(reader)` as a variable? For instance, if I define `NewList = list(reader)` I get an error `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`. Second question, the `list(reader)` seems to add and extra `[` and `]` at the beginning and the end of the list, e.g. `[[a,b,c]]`. How do you make the list just `[a,b,c]`?

Comment: @MarkClements `list()` will read all the rows in list of lists format, so read one row at a time. `for row in reader: ...` . All the operations related to that file object should be done inside that with statement block, otherwise you'll get  ` I/O operation on closed file`.